# Powershell formatting a USB stick in FAT32 or NTFS

Tags: powershell, formatting, usb

I have been trying to find a solution for a USB problem whereby I want to merge two small PS1 scripts into one, to be able to choose individual USB's to format in FAT32 or NTFS. Also to set DiskNumber, DriveLetters and NewFileSystemLabel.

****USB-FORMAT IN FAT32.PS1****

```
cls
"list disk" | diskpart

do {
write-host -nonewline "Enter a USB DISK number then press ENTER: "
$inputString = read-host
$value = $inputString -as [Double]
$ok = $value -ne $NULL
if ( -not $ok ) { write-host "You must enter a numeric value" }
}
until ( $ok )

write-host "You entered DISK: $value "
Get-Disk $value

PAUSE 

Initialize-Disk $value -PartitionStyle MBR
New-Partition –DiskNumber $value -UseMaximumSize –IsActive:$true
Format-Volume –FileSystem FAT32 –DriveLetter I 
              -NewFileSystemLabel "USB-FAT32"

bootsect.exe /NT60 I:

"YOUR USB IS NOW FORMATTED AND BOOTABLE"

PAUSE
```

****USB-FORMAT IN NTFS.PS1****

```
cls
"list disk" | diskpart


do {
write-host -nonewline "Enter a USB DISK number then press ENTER: "
$inputString = read-host
$value = $inputString -as [Double]
$ok = $value -ne $NULL
if ( -not $ok ) { write-host "You must enter a numeric value" }
}
until ( $ok )

write-host "You entered DISK: $value "
Get-Disk $value

PAUSE 

Initialize-Disk $value -PartitionStyle MBR
New-Partition –DiskNumber $value -UseMaximumSize –IsActive:$true
Format-Volume –FileSystem NTFS –DriveLetter I 
              -NewFileSystemLabel "USB-NTFS"

bootsect.exe /NT60 I:

"YOUR USB IS NOW FORMATTED AND BOOTABLE"

PAUSE
```

---

I have not used Powershell before, only Batch files, so I am at a complete loss as to which Commands I should be using and how to use Variables.
I managed to put together the two PS1 files above, from the internet. 
They both work separately but only with a single USB inserted into the PC.
I am using Windows 10 PRO (v1709,Redstone 3,Fall Creators Update).

The real solution for me would be variables for
DiskNumber (up to No.10 - includes 6x HDD & 4x USB)
FileSystem (FAT32 or NTFS)  DriveLetter (C to Z) 
NewFileSystemLabel ("USB-FAT32" or "USB-NTFS")

ANY HELP OR ADVICE WOULD BE SINCERELY APPRECIATED!
THANKS FOR LOOKING!!
KIND REGARDS, MIKE

Comment: Use `help about_Parameters` to see how parameter variables are created and used. When you have tried something and it is not working, Stack Overflow is a good place to ask questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - request for programming services. No effort. No learning.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using parameters? Try adding this block at the top:

```
param (
  [string]$Format
)
```

Replace the position inside the `Initialize-Disk` call where you need to specify `NTFS` or `FAT32` with `$Format`, and then you can simply specify the format you want as a parameter to the script, like this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> C:\Path\To\Script.ps1 NTFS # or FAT32
```

You can also expand this to more values you need input for; copy the middle line, replace `string` with `int` if it's a number, and change the parameter's name (it needs to keep the `$`), then you can use it wherever you need that piece of information.

Good luck on learning PowerShell; it's really useful once you learn all the things it can do.

Comment: I am sure that @Milke-m5 will also find `[ValidateSet('FAT32', 'NTFS')]` to be useful.